# How to configure JNDITemplate using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I am trying to migrate one of JMS application configured with springframework.
Before migration it was working fine but once I migrated it, it start giving me an erro.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/GenericsHelper
                at
```

and the spring confguration Looks like this

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">
                localhost
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">
                org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is java code that is uses spring configuration file to create the context.

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

                BeanDefinition jmsConfigBean = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(TestMessageSelector.class).addConstructorArg(testApp.getUser().get_empNo()).getBeanDefinition();
                beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("TestMessageSelector", jmsConfigBean);

                BeanDefinition jndiEnvironmentBean = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(TestJndiEnvironment.class).addConstructorArg(testApp.mode).getBeanDefinition();
                beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("TestJndiEnvironment", jndiEnvironmentBean);

                GenericApplicationContext genericContext = new GenericApplicationContext(beanFactory);
                genericContext.refresh();
                new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "Spring_JMS_Config.xml" }, genericContext);
```

To me it seems to be jar issue. But I really do not from where this GenericsHelper jar is coming. May it is coming from some old spring.jar. But someone help to configure this configuration with spring 4.
It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you are using maven do `mvn dependency:tree` and check your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

`GenericsHelper` was in older versions of Spring (before 2.5 even).

You probably have mismatched versions of spring jars on your classpath.

All your spring jars must be the same version; you can use `-verbose` to see class loading activity (and which jars they are loaded from). It will likely be some class loaded just before you get the exception that is dependent on `GenericsHelper`.

Comment: I am using spring-core, spring-beans. spring-context of version 4.3.2.

Comment: All three are same in terms of version. One more, do I need to change any config in spring configuration file. too.

Comment: Yes, but something is trying to load a version of that class; if it's not Spring, it must be some other class, either in a library jar or your code directly. `-verbose` will help you find which one.